# Portable unix-like environment for Windows

Tags: windows, unix, vim

I am trying to put together a portable set of files/scripts that will enable me to mimic a unix like environment on Windows.

I do not want to install anything. The setup needs to be able to live on a thumbdrive for example. Currently I am using [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) to provide grep, and more. Im adding these to the Windows PATH environment variable in the current console session by

```
cd <pathToUnxUtils>
path = %PATH%;%CD%
```

For Vim (my preferred editor) I am using the "Win32 console executable" (http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) vim.exe. If I have that in a drive such as \vim\vim73\vim.exe then $VIMRUNTIME is \vim\vim73, which is where my vimrc lives.

I am trying to get some syntax highlighting and indenting going next, which I believe I need to add the appropriate .vim scripts to $VIMRUNTIME\syntax and $VIMRUNTIME\indent
but it does not seem to work.

I am using the console executible instead of something like gVim (which probably does more of what I want "out-of-the-box") because I want to be able to send commands to the same shell using the ! command. gVim does not allow that (correct me if I am wrong)

Lastly, has anyone experienced trouble with "tail" from UnxUtils working on Vista?

I know this probably seems like a stupid way to go about things, but I am really trying to make this work. Id be happy with getting these bits of Unix goodness going on Windows.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Check out cygwin portable: http://symbiosoft.net/cygwinportable

Or this guide on how to make regular cygwin run on portable devices: http://sites.google.com/site/devinsezer/Home/software/portable-cygwin

The advantage of cygwin over a thin emulation layer like UnxUtils is that it includes a fully working X11 server so you can even run GUI unix apps if you need to  (gitk for example, if you're using git)

Comment: cygwin portable sounds promising. That would be most ideal if it could effectively be carried around without installation. I am trying to leave no footpint on the windows box other than perhaps copying my directory of files to the machine (which could then just be deleted after my use). Thanks for the link, I will check it out

Comment: Does the "CygWin Portable" allow several installations in parallel? If they still go to registry for local settings and mount points, "CygWin Portable" would break on Windows which already have (e.g. old, out-dated) installation of CygWin.

Answer (score 2):

I've had some troubles with `UnxUtils` before re currency - they don't seem to be as up to date as the [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) stuff (for example, `TextUtils` at 2.1 instead of 5.3).

I've simply downloaded the [executables](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) and required libraries for what I've needed (no install needed if you avoid the setup packages, just copy and go).

If you click on the package names on the left of that second link above (not the "Setup" on the right), it allows you to download both the executable plus all dependencies on a single page.

My particular needs for a recent project were met with `sed` and about four DLL files, no installation, no impinging on the environment or registry. In short, ideal for running from a memory stick or standalone CD.

I must, at some point, put together a CD with the entire suite on it. I used to carry around CygWin but the necessity to install was a pain.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using MobaXterm from Mobatek.

http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/

It's not a complete envoirement, but is quite suficcient. 
Just download and run!

[image: Tabbed interface]

It have an (ba)sh, with X, sed, grep, awk, rsync, wget, sftp, scp; and some extra plugins (standalone files to put in the same dir) to VIM, EMACS, perl python, Gcc, gdb, mplayer, svn, git, lua graphviz...

It still provides many protocols (RDP, VNC, SSH, telnet, rsh, FTP, SFTP and XDMCP).

Answer (score 1):

Either [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/) or [CH](http://www.softintegration.com/products/chstandard/) will do that, there is a specifically portable VIM at [portable apps](http://portableapps.com/apps)

Comment: Thanks for the leads. I will take a look at those options

Answer (score 1):

[Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) and [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) provides all you need. I have used both and I think MSYS runs faster than Cygwin on a Windows machine. Cygwin emulates the UNIX environment whereas MSYS is port of the GNU utils to Windows.

Another option to get portable GNU utils is to install [Portable MsysGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cygwin.com/ is very popular.

update: oh, never mind - I don't think it can be xcopy deployed.

-Oisin

Comment: CygWin keeps configuration in the Windows registry. Not so portable. In fact, it is impossible to have two instances of CygWin on the same system. Was a major PITA when I needed that.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with running Cygwin on a thumbdrive.  I haven't run it on machines where older versions are installed.  But I don't expect to have that problem often.

Here is what I did: http://fadedbluesky.com/2011/portable-cygwin/